# SVG element to PNG file with C#

Tags: c#, svg, bounding-box, inkscape

I'm trying to convert SVG into a PNG file. My main problem is not the convertion itself (I can do it with few line of code), but is the centering of the SVG element I want to sender into the "window" that get's rendered.

I use SVG engine (https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) and my idea is to get the element I want to render, then  reposition it at the origin and then set width and height of the svg document to the width/height of the element.
here's the code:

```
var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(filename);
var el =(SvgVisualElement) svgDocument.GetElementById("MyId");

// set in the origin
el.Transforms.Add(new SvgTranslate(-el.Bounds.X, -el.Bounds.Y));

// set doc dimensions
svgDocument.Width = el.Bounds.Width;
svgDocument.Height = el.Bounds.Height;

bitmap.Save("PNGFile", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Unfortunally it doesn't work that way. 
Here's an example of svg that doesn't work (it's lenthy, so I cut the relevant parts):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="70.125473"
   height="190.98564"
   id="svg6678"
   version="1.1">
   <g id="MyId">
    <g
       transform="translate(-2375.7448,475.88408)"
       id="Texture:door_single_rocks_gear">
      <path
         id="path9179-8-2-8-71-4-2-7"
         d="..." style="color:#000000;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;fill:#5b3636;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1.53245842;marker:none;enable-background:accumulate" />
      <path
         id="path9179-8-2-8-71-4-6"
         d="..." style="color:#000000;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;fill:#815656;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1.53245842;marker:none;enable-background:accumulate" />
      <path
         id="path4080-5-2"
         d="..."
         style="fill:#866262;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
      <path
         id="path7662-1-1-4-9"
         d="..."
         style="fill:#5b3636;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
      <path
         id="path7662-1-1-4-5-5"
         d="..."
         style="fill:#5b3636;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
    </g>
    <g
       id="Texture:door_single_rocks"
       inkscape:label="#g5299"
       inkscape:export-filename="C:\Users\stefano.liboni\Dropbox\AndroidStudio\AsteroidRage\scenes_source\door_single_rocks.png"
       inkscape:export-xdpi="199.88191"
       inkscape:export-ydpi="199.88191">
      <path style="color:#000000;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;fill:#5b3636;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:3;marker:none;enable-background:accumulate"
         d="..."
         id="rect4972-3-8-9" />
      <path
         id="rect4972-9"
         d="..." style="color:#000000;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;fill:#815656;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#5b3636;stroke-width:1.0026859;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker:none;enable-background:accumulate" />
      <path
         style="fill:#5b3636;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
         d="..."
         id="path7662-1-1-4-5-5-0" />
      <path
         style="fill:#5b3636;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
         d="..."
         id="path7662-1-1-4-5-5-03-9" />
      <path
         style="fill:#5b3636;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
         d="..."
         id="path7662-1-1-4-5-5-03" />
    </g>
    <g
       id="AnimatedTexture:door_single_rocks_led"
       inkscape:label="#g5295">
      <path
         id="path9095-7"
         d="..."
         style="fill:#9486ff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.07693017;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <path
         id="path9095-7-5-1"
         d="..."
         style="fill:#9486ff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.07693017;stroke-opacity:1" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see there is a **g** element **MyId** full of other g elements and some paths. I add an image of it rendered in inkscape[image: the svg rendered in inkscape].

Once I get the bounds of the element (which is the one at the bottom left) in my code I get: 
**{X = -1502.69763 Y = 668.7914 Width = 2514.11938 Height = 870.0564}**

It seems wrong since the element is just 141px of width and 395px of height...
If I run the code on that file the output is:
[image]

So the PNG has a lot of unused space, both y, width and height of the png are wrong. The right ones would be:

```
svgDocument.X = 0;
svgDocument.Y = -476;
svgDocument.Width = 141;
svgDocument.Height = 395;
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I know that inkscape would do it right (I used to use it), but there's a bug since at least 3years that they don't bother to solve that prevents inkscape to run in silent mode if you specify "verb" in the command line. So uning it is a pain because for every file it opens the UI and takes 3-4secs to do it...

Comment: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE
----------------------------------------------------

As I supposed it has to do with the transfrom attribute of the **g** element inside the element I want to render. If I get rid of all transform attribute it works fine, not just for this example but for even more complicated geomeries.
How can take those transform into consideration?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the inkscape CLI problem you have? I am using that successfully for more or less the same task you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pushed by the comment of ccprog I found out that the UI was openend by inkscape because I was doing also other stuff in the same command I run.

Actually running inkscape as:

MyFile.svg --export-id=ElementIdToRender --export-id-only --export-dpi=200 --export-png="TargetFile"

Does the job.

Still to understand why the SVG library gives strange numbers as Bounds for **g** elements containing one or more children with transform attribute set, but at the moment I can go on.
Tnx

Answer (score 1):

I have not found if there is a documentation for the library. I've looked around in the source, but mainly what I can explain is the SVG part of things. Maybe there are simpler ways the engine provides itself.

`transform` attributes on the root svg element are legitimate, but in the context of what you want to accomplish, they are more confusing than helpfull, since there are other attributes that result in transformations, but are written in a different form.

An `<svg>` element provides attributes that match what you want to accomplish much more directly:

- `x` and `y` attributes on an outermost svg element are ignored.
- `width` and `height` describe the **output** dimensions the image is rendered into. So they should reflect the final "window" dimensions. If the SVG initially has dimensions not fitting your "window", change them.
- [`viewBox`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) describes which part of the **internal** SVG viewport (the coordinate system of the root element) should be rendered. This **not** what the `SVGVisualElement.Bounds` struct for a selected element returns. (Values relative to the coordinate system of the element itself, but excluding all parent element transformations) I can't find any function in the library that would get you the values you need.
- [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) describes how the rendered part is fit into the output window. For example, `XMidYMid meet`, which is the default, means: Size the viewBox area with the maximum size so that it just fits into the width/height without overflowing in any direction, and position it in the center.

While I don't know how to get the needed values of the bounding box from the library, other programs deliver them without problem:

- `inkscape -I MyID` in the command line
- in the browser via Javascript `document.getElementById("MyId").getBBox()`

Comment: Tnx for the help. I already change the width and height of the svg document, but using the Bounds property of the element I want to render, which in turn seems wrong since it gives too high values... getting rid of all transform everything works fine and Bounds gives the right values. There should be a bug in the SVG library...

Comment: You could veryfy the values of Bounds by testing them with differernt software. Open the .svg directly in a modern browser, press <F12> to open the developer tools, in the integrated console, type `document.getElementById("MyId").getBBox()`. The result should be an object that matches the properties of Bounds for that element.

Comment: After reading the library sources again, I am now sure Bounds does not deliver the needed values - which is not a bug, but missing documentation of what that property is. Well, there *is* a bug: [Bounds doesn't account for child transforms](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/issues/331), but even resolving that wouldn't give you what you need.

Comment: I think that's my problem... the transform on the child. Tnx for pointing it out.